# Symplectic Hodge Star and Koszul differential

Tags: algebraic-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $M = \text{Spec}(R)$ be a symplectic affine variety of dimension $n$ with the symplectic form $\omega$. There is the symplectic Hodge star $\star: \Omega^k_{M} \to \Omega^{2n-k}_{M}$ given by the condition that for any $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega^k$ we should have
$$\beta \wedge \alpha = \Lambda^k G(\beta, \alpha) \cdot v_n$$
where
$$G(-, -): TM^* \times TM^* \to R$$ is a bivector field corresponding to $\omega$ and $v_n = \omega^n/n!$.

I want to understand the first nontrivial (for me) case: $M = T^* \mathbb{A}^2$. In this case $\omega = dx_1 dx_2 + dx_3 dx_4$ and $v_2 = dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4$.
Also,
$$G = \frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_1}} \frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_2}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_3}} \frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_4}}.$$
It seems to me that we have the following

$\star(f) = f dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4$

$\star(\alpha) = \alpha \wedge \omega$ where $\alpha \in \Omega^1_{M}$

$\star(\zeta) = -\zeta$ for $\zeta \in \Omega^{2}_{M}$

$\star(\eta) = i_{G} \eta$ where $\eta \in \Omega^{3}_{M}$ and $i_{G}$ is the contraction with $G$.

OK, then let us see how the Koszul differential works and it is the place where I met a contradiction in math (of course, the problem is with me but I cannot figure it out).

$\textbf{Setup.}$ The Koszul differential $B: \Omega^{k}_{M} \to \Omega^{k-1}_{M}$ has two interpretations, the first one is $B = [i_G, d]$. The second is $B = (-1)^{k+1} \star d \star.$

$\textbf{My misunderstanding.}$ Let $x \in \Omega^3_{M}$. The first definition gives $Bx = i_G dx - d i_{G}x$. The second definition gives $Bx = \star d \star x = \star d i_{G} x = -d i_{G} x$. As we see, we should have $i_{G} dx=0$ which is not the case, for example, for $x_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4.$

$\textbf{My quesion.}$ Where is the mistake? Or, can we write down the star isomorphism in the general case? I think it is related to the multiplication by $\omega^{n-k}$, but mostly I'm interested how to write down the formula for $\star: \Omega^{k}_{M} \to \Omega^{2n-k}_{M}$ for $k>n$. Is there any reference?